# bad operand types for binary operator compiling error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, operators

for a game i'm making I need to place a tetris-like piece on a 10x10 game board.

I want to return "offboard" if the player tries to put the piece on a cell that is outside the board

For this, I've made an initial method that returns true if the piece goes offfboard.

x and y are the coordinates of my board which I made using a 2d array with 10 rows and 10 columns

i want to print our a string saying "offboard" if the any part of the piece goes outside the area of the game board.

```
    //Return true if the cell is offboard
    private boolean isOffBoard(int x, int y){
        if(board[x][y] < 0 || board[x][y] > 9){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But when i try to compile, it gives me an error saying:

bad operand types for binary operator '<'

first type Sqaure, second type int

I understand that the operator and number i'm using doesn't match the board's 2d array structure, but I really don't know how to fix it so it works properly.

I really need help fixing this error so I can continue the coding for the rest of my game.

Comment: Why don't you just use `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 9 || y > 9)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare a `Square` with `0` (and `9`). Instead of trying to compare to the board's contents, compare to the size of the array. (Additionally, don't use `if...return true`. Just return the value.)

```
private boolean isOffBoard(int x, int y){
    return (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= board.length || y >= board[x].length);
}
```